# Ping using Guzzle Http php

Tags: php, guzzle

I want to use guzzle http for ping.
I dont care about the response.
Just request is enough.
**No need of response.**
After request the code need to exits. Dont wait for response.

I tried to do with async.

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$promise1 = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'http://localhost/test/?id=from_async1');

$promise2 = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'http://localhost/test/?id=from_async2');

$promise3 = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'http://localhost/test/?id=from_async3');

$promise1->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) {

});

$promise2->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) {

});

$promise3->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) {

});
$promise1->wait();

$promise2->wait();

$promise3->wait();
```

But still this script waits for all response to come back.

How to get the script work without waiting for response? Any thoughts?

Comment: If you dont want to wait for the promise to resolve, then why do you use `wait`?

Comment: I tried without wait, But result was no request made.